# SQL - algorithm for grouping dates without Procedural Language

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, date, grouping

Hello and thanks in advance for any help, I work in the Oracle SQL environment.

My problem is specified in this picture:

[image]

***Input:***

I have date intervals belonging for a customer which never go beyond the scope of one month. I need to connect those intervals where the end of first interval is the end of a month and the next interval starts the first day of the next month (that is the only way they connect).

In the column **"days between"** it is already obvious, that when there is a start of a new interval the number is higher than 1 and when the current row belongs to an interval there is 1.

***Some specifics:***

- For 1 user there can be more than two intervals, in the example there is one user with three intervals
- **The intervals can be several months long = occupying several rows.**
- The spacing between intervals can be also several months long.

***Output:***

Specific example of the desirable output is in the attached picture. Simply - I want for each row to be specified when does the whole interval, in which the row interval is included, start and end.

```
Data:
ID  Start date  End date    Last start date Last end date   Days between
12  21.03.2016  31.03.2016                                  1
12  01.04.2016  04.04.2016  21.03.2016      31.03.2016      1
12  28.04.2016  30.04.2016  01.04.2016      04.04.2016      24
12  01.05.2016  20.05.2016  28.04.2016      30.04.2016      1
12  06.06.2016  30.06.2016  01.05.2016      20.05.2016      17
12  01.07.2016  13.07.2016  06.06.2016      30.06.2016      1
```

Comment: You should at least include some sample data in your actual question.  This sounds like a gaps and islands problem, which would require substantial effort to solve.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to posting to this site - where can I upload some excel or something? This is the last part of a big problem I am solving. I will try to work something out in the meantime, I was curious if someone solved something similar.

Comment: Include _text_ in your actual question.  Add four spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: I am sorry, the four spaces did not indent the text, could you help me? Thank you

Comment: " This sounds like a gaps and islands problem, which would require substantial effort to solve." Thank you very much for the name of the problem. I think I should be able to program this from this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979745/complex-gaps-and-islands-issue/38986476#38986476 if I am succesful I will mark this as comepleted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Tim-biegeleisen for the problem name again, from there it was so easy! I will definitely remember this solution in the future.

I solved the problem in two easy steps.

First use a dummy variable for those intervals, where there is a gap:

```
    case when days_between=1 then 0 else 1 end as gap
```

Then we distribute the intervals according the gaps

```
    sum(gap) over (partition by ID order by start_date)
```

From that we just group by ID and the new variable and we are done.